# Select from a table variable

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.2

I am trying to save the result of a `SELECT` query, pass it, and reuse it in another PL/pgSQL function:

```
DECLARE
  table_holder my_table; --the type of table_holder is my_table;
  result text;

BEGIN
  SELECT * INTO table_holder FROM table_holder ;

  result = another_function(table_holder);  
  return result;
END
```

The code for `another_function(table_holder my_table)`, respectively:

```
BEGIN

  RETURN QUERY
  SELECT col FROM table_holder where id = 1;

END
```

Is it possible to run a `SELECT` query on a variable? If not, is there a way to get around this limitation?

I am using PostgreSQL 9.2.

Comment: You already have thevalue in the varaible. What else do you want to select ?

Comment: @Safeer I want to pass this variable to another function.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There are no "table variables" in plpgsql. That's something you would find in SQL Server.

Use a [**temporary table**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html) instead:

```
BEGIN

CREATE TEMP TABLE table_holder AS
SELECT * FROM table_holder
WHERE <some condition>
ORDER BY <some expression>
;

...

END
```

A temporary table exists for the lifetime of a session. To drop it at the end of the function (or an enclosing transaction) automatically, use `ON COMMIT DROP` in the creating statement.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE table_holder ON COMMIT DROP AS
SELECT ...
```

The temporary table is visible in the same session, but not outside.

One alternative would be to use [*cursors* in PL/pgSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-cursors.html).

More alternatives:

- [SELECT multiple rows and columns into a record variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24949266/select-multiple-rows-and-columns-into-a-record-variable/24964374#24964374)

Comment: A key difference between using temp tables and table variables is that a temp table remains visible until the *transaction* commits or it's dropped. Multiple or re-entrant calls to the function can have surprising and unexpected results because they see the same table, not isolated per-function table variables. I think temp tables are also a lot less efficient than tablevars. Whenever possible avoid using temp tables in stored procs. You can often do what you need to by passing refcursors or by having one function `SELECT` from another directly.

Comment: Temp tables live until the end of the *session* (not just transaction) by default.

Comment: Yes, unless `ON COMMIT DROP`, as you've used above. I should've mentioned that explicitly.