# Concatenate return type for a crosstab() query from another query

Tags: sql, postgresql, dynamic-sql, crosstab, postgresql-9.3

I can't post my original query here, it's too complex. So I am explaining my problem with a sample query:

Working pivot query:

```
Select pivot.* from public.crosstab($$ select 'na' as na, 1 as analysis,100 as value 
 union all select 'ba' as na, 2 as analysis,100 as value $$,
 $$ VALUES ('1'), ('2')$$
) as pivot (na text, "1" integer,"2" integer)
```

But I would like to use it like this:

```
Select pivot.* from public.crosstab($$ select 'na' as na, 1 as analysis,100 as value 
 union all select 'ba' as na, 2 as analysis,100 as value $$,
 $$ VALUES ('1'), ('2')$$
) as pivot select '(na text,"1" integer,"2" integer)'
```

I want to add the return type from a query (bold emphasis). How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Clear test case

First I formated and clarified your example:

```
SELECT * FROM public.crosstab(
   $$VALUES ('na', 1, 100)   -- VALUES expression does the same, shorter
          , ('ba', 2, 300)$$ -- no column names needed (ignored anyway)
  ,$$VALUES ('1'), ('2')$$
   ) AS pivot (na text, co11 int, col2 int)  -- sane column names
```

Input table:

```
col1  key  val
---------------
na    1    100
ba    2    300
```

Output table

```
na    co11    col2
--------------------
na    100     <NULL>
ba    <NULL>  300
```

You can pick output column *names* freely, no need to stick to unwieldy names like `"1"`, `"2"`. Only the data *types* have to match.

#### Dynamic return type

You cannot provide the column definition list from a query. We have had many similar requests here on SO. They all clash with the nature of SQL, which does not accept a return type "after the fact". Must be declared with the query, at least at the time of executing it.

You would have to build the `crosstab()` query with the output of the `SELECT` query you want to add in your 2nd example. *Two* round trips to the server.

**But** we can read a **well know type from the system catalogs** - that's what `SELECT * FROM tbl` does after all. I have tried hard and implemented what I found in this related answer:

- [Dynamic alternative to pivot with CASE and GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506199/dynamic-alternative-to-pivot-with-case-and-group-by/15514334#15514334)

My function `crosstab_n()` is probably your best shot. **Read the linked answer!**

It's a wrapper around `crosstab()` that takes the query string (just like `crosstab()`) and an additional **polymorphic** parameter that provides the return type. We still cannot pass the return type *on the fly*. The only acceptable way for SQL is to read it from the system catalog. So we install a composite type "on the fly" by way of creating a **temporary table**:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE my_pivot (na text, col1 int, col2 int);

SELECT * FROM crosstab_n(
    $$VALUES ('na', 1, 100), ('ba', 2, 100)$$
    ,NULL::my_pivot
    );
```

Result as above. Voilà!

If you want the temp table to last for the transaction only, add `ON COMMIT DROP` to it. Both statements must be executed in *one* transaction then.  Details:

- [Select from a table variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17873735/select-from-a-table-variable/17873935#17873935)