# Select elements that are absent in a table from a list of value

Tags: sql, select, plsql

I have a table T with id and labels

```
ID  LABEL
1   label_1
2   label_2
3   label_3
```

I have a list of labels:

```
('label_1', 'label_4', 'label_6' )
```

I would like to select those that do not exist in table T. In my case I would get 'label_4' and 'label_6'.
How can I do that in SQL?

---

### EDIT 1

Those labels are external values. I would like to print values that do not exist in my table in a log file, probably using a spool

---

EDIT 2

I am currently trying to put all my values in a table using pl/SQL since it is basically a huge list of values. I have this:

```
DECLARE
  type array_t is varray(603) of varchar2(50 BYTE);
  labels array_t := array_t(
        '210',
                'label_1',
                'label_6',
                'label_4'
  );
BEGIN
  For i in labels LOOP

    Insert Into TEMP_LABEL (LABEL)
    Values (i);

  END LOOP;
  commit;
END;
```

but I get the following error: `pls-00456 item is not a cursor`
I am stuck here.

Comment: Do `label_4` and `label_6` exist in a lookup table somewhere?  Or are they external values which may not be in the database at all?  What exactly did you want your results to look like?

Comment: Those labels are external values. I would like to print values that do not exist in my table in a log file, probably using a `spool`

Comment: The answer depends on your database engine, which you didn't specify.

Comment: Are you able to create a temp table or table variable with these external values? What database system are you using? After creating a temp table, you should be able to do a ```LEFT JOIN``` then filter on ```NULL``` values to get what you need.

Comment: Does this mean that what I am asking to do is impossible without storing my external values in a (temporary) table?

Comment: Not impossible, but if you are wanting to use SQL to do this (rather than application code or a programmatic approach) then using a table makes sense, as other commenters have mentioned, if you let us know what database engine you are using, there may be a way to accomplish this without a table - using something like PL/pgSQL (for Postgres)

Comment: I am now trying ot put all of my vlues into a table using PL/SQL. Please have a look at my second edit.

Comment: For using a CURSOR, you want to declare that, see the manual here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-cursors.html For using a temp table, here is a good start http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17873735/select-from-a-table-variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b2903/9) (and [postgres version](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0b45d/1)) for a solution using a table

The pertinent query is the following:

```
   SELECT T_TEMP.LABEL, T.LABEL
     FROM T_TEMP
LEFT JOIN T
       ON T_TEMP.LABEL = T.LABEL
    WHERE T.LABEL IS NULL;
```

If there is a strong reason for not using a table to store these values, please let us know.

Depending on how huge the data set is, choosing between the following queries can have an impact on performance (see this [excellent explanation comparing the methods](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/16/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-postgresql/)):

```
-- LEFT JOIN / IS NULL
SELECT    T_TEMP.LABEL, T.LABEL
FROM      T_TEMP
LEFT JOIN T ON T_TEMP.LABEL = T.LABEL
WHERE     T.LABEL IS NULL;

-- NOT EXISTS
SELECT  T_TEMP.LABEL
FROM    T_TEMP
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
    (
    SELECT  T.LABEL
    FROM    T
    WHERE   T_TEMP.LABEL = T.LABEL
    );

-- NOT IN    
SELECT  T_TEMP.LABEL
FROM    T_TEMP
WHERE   LABEL NOT IN
    (
    SELECT  T.LABEL
    FROM    T
    );
```

As the dataset grows, the LEFT JOIN / IS NULL or NOT EXISTS should perform better, but according the the execution plan in [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0b45d/1), the NOT IN seems to be performing with the lowest cost.

Comment: Thank you the `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL` method seems to work. Strangely enough the `NOT IN` method does not output any result, even though it should return the same result than the others. I will try to find out where my (very likely) error comes from.

Comment: If you have one of them working, I would stick with that, but if you do want ```NOT IN``` to work, double check that you have ```WHERE LABEL NOT IN``` as opposed to just ```WHERE NOT IN``` - it differs from ```WHERE NOT EXISTS```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer before more information was provided in "EDIT 2".  I think more context-specific information is needed.  Anyways, this code returns rows of labels not in original table:

```
CREATE TABLE OriginalTable (Id INT, Label VARCHAR(20));

INSERT INTO OriginalTable (Id, Label)
VALUES (1, 'label_1'), (2, 'label_2'), (3, 'label_3');

-- Create a table with the labels you want to compare
CREATE TABLE ComparisonTable (Id INT, Label VARCHAR(20));

INSERT INTO ComparisonTable (Id, Label)
VALUES (1, 'label_1'), (2, 'label_4'), (3, 'label_6');

SELECT Label
FROM ComparisonTable
WHERE Label NOT IN (SELECT Label FROM OriginalTable);
```