# How to select from a variable in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I'm creating a function and I need to get the largest and smallest results from an average score calculation.  So far it looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.my_func()
    RETURNS NUMERIC
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $function$
DECLARE
    all_user_average_scores record;
    max_avg numeric;
    min_avg numeric;
BEGIN
    
        SELECT user_uuid, AVG(score) as avg_score
            INTO all_user_average_scores
            FROM user_scores
            GROUP BY user_uuid;

    SELECT max(avg_score) INTO max_raw FROM all_user_average_scores;
    SELECT min(avg_score) INTO min_raw FROM all_user_average_scores;

    -- Do some more stuff here

    RETURN final_result;
END;
$function$;
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR:  relation "all_user_average_scores" does not exist
```

Any ideas?  I've tried the `:=` syntax as well and I get the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out you can't save a table in a variable. The solution is to use a temporary table as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17873935/9519817)

Comment: You don't need a temp table for this

Answer (score 2):

As you have seen, you cannot use a variable like a table. Moreover, `SELECT ... INTO` will only store **the first row** of the result set in the variable.

In your case, you don't need a variable at all:

```
SELECT max(avg_score), min(avg_score) INTO max_raw, min_raw
FROM (SELECT AVG(score) as avg_score
      FROM user_scores
      GROUP BY user_uuid) AS q;
```

Alternatively, you could use a CTE:

```
WITH q AS (
   SELECT AVG(score) as avg_score
   FROM user_scores
   GROUP BY user_uuid
)
SELECT max(avg_score), min(avg_score) INTO max_raw, min_raw
FROM q;
```

For more complicated cases, a temporary table might be the best solution.